# how i can get last 10 days records with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

my table structure was like

```
CREATE TABLE `survey` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `submitdate` datetime default NULL,
 `answer` varchar(5) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=499 ;
```

Now I want to calculate last 10 days records. Suppose no record on particular day. it should be zero.

the output is like

```
date         count
19-11-2012   10
18-11-2012   30 
13-11-2012   0 
      .
      .
```

i have used query  like

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) , DATE( submitdate ) 
FROM survey t
WHERE t.submitdate >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 10 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY DATE( submitdate ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

output is

```
count(*)    date(submitdate)
1   2012-11-13
2   2012-11-14
1   2012-11-15
3   2012-11-16
6   2012-11-17
```

not giving 0 for no records with dates.

Comment: This looks like the textbook example of an [insertion anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies). Dates only appear in the table if there's a submission associated with them, so your table can't represent dates with zero submissions. If this is a common problem, you might need a second table for dates (and a way to automatically update it). Otherwise, just use a loop to construct a query like the one fthiella suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT days.day, count(survey.id)
FROM
  (select curdate() as day
   union select curdate() - interval 1 day
   union select curdate() - interval 2 day
   union select curdate() - interval 3 day
   union select curdate() - interval 4 day
   union select curdate() - interval 5 day
   union select curdate() - interval 6 day
   union select curdate() - interval 7 day
   union select curdate() - interval 8 day
   union select curdate() - interval 9 day) days
  left join survey
   on days.day = survey.submitdate
group by
  days.day
```

(if submitdate contanis date and time, you should replace the line `on days.day = survey.submitdate` with `on days.day = DATE(survey.submitdate)`)

Comment: I think this is the only way to do what the poster wants, considering the insertion anomaly where dates with zero submissions are never represented in the database. It could probably be generalized more using a loop to construct the query.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  the answer is giving only 0 s. almost 6 of the given dates have records.                                                     o/p is day count(survey.id)
2012-11-09 0
2012-11-10 0
2012-11-11 0
2012-11-12 0
.
.

Comment: if you get 10 rows with the last 10 days, and all 0s, it means that the join did not succeed... did you try to replace the on clause with this: `on days.day = DATE(survey.submitdate)` ?

Comment: is there any other optimized query to get the last 7 days without today date?

Comment: @Gunaseelan you could substitute each `curdate()` with `(select max(day) from yourtable)` but of course the risk is that it gets executed 7 times, you could then use a cross join instead

Comment: @fthiella Thanks for the comment. I found a better one using between

Comment: @Gunaseelan between is often a better solution. But if a day is missing the query with between won't return the missing day - which is fine, but the OP wanted to return all 10 days with 0 if the day is missing..if is not a problem for you just use between :)

Answer (score 9):

You can try something like this to get the output:-

```
 SELECT * FROM survey t WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY);
```

or you can try this:-

```
 SELECT * FROM survey t WHERE t.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )
```

Check [Date_Add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) documentation

Comment: ans is count(*)
          13

Comment: I couldnt understand your answer. Could you please tell me what you are getting when you are running this?

Comment: Add Group by `t.date` in the end of query.